# python update users in active directory

Tags: python, active-directory

Is it possible with active_directory or pyad to update users' properties ?

At the moment I tried:

```
user = active_directory.find_user ( "msala" )
print user.sAMAccountName, user.givenName, user.sn, user.mail
user.mail = "massimo.sala@bubusette.com"
user.update()
```

Comment: If you look here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyad it looks like you use `user.set_attribute(<thing>, <attribute>)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I list the properties and methods of "user" ... I found :

> user.set()

so I solved.

Answer (score 1):

1. First in Server Manager (2008r), open "View", tick "Advanced Features".
2. Go to a user in AD and view properties. Go to "Attribute Editor" and search for the name of the attribute.

In python:

```
user.update_attribute("mail", "my_email@domain.tld")
```